# Exponentiation equivalent to summation/product notation

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm familiar with both summation and product notations. Is there an equivalent for exponentiation?

Specifically, what notation could I use to represent 10 to the 10th to the 10th to the ... to the 10th, x times?

Comment: Please feel free to improve this question or adjust the tags to be more appropriate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation does this answer your question?

Comment: Actually, the thing you asked is not quite what I suppose you mean. You probably mean something like $$a_1^{a_2^{a_3^{\cdots^{a_n}}}}$$

Comment: @blamethelag Up-arrow notation will definitely work, thanks! If you add this as an answer I will accept and upvote, since you beat out ProductivePerson by four minutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean tetration: Raising a number to itself that number of times. To denote tetration you put the number of powers in the top left corner of the number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tetration

Comment: Tetration is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I upvoted, but feel obliged to give the checkmark to blamethelag since his answer is also correct and he beat you by four minutes. :( If he doesn't add an answer I'll mark this one as correct in a few days.